# Min column width in kendo grids

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Apparently Telerik thinks this is a solved problem (as it's documented). I was reading this ...

[Enfocing min width on Kendo Grid (jQuery) when grid has hidden columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072738/enfocing-min-width-on-kendo-grid-jquery-when-grid-has-hidden-columns)

... which in turn led me to telerik's documentation here ...

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/apply-minimum-width-during-column-resize

which seems to imply this is done deal ...

[image]

... those columns are not >= 300px wide!

So what am i missing here ?

I need a means to say "this column MUST be no thinner than x number of pixels" and have it stick when I resize the grid however that happens.

I think this dojo example only takes in to account the grey splitter bar in the dojo and not the window being resized.

**Further details**

When building a grid and making it scrollable + resizable and shrinking it in height there's a scrollbar applied to the row set for the height.
I believe the same should be true horizontally and that the "grid" should shrink but it's column set should be scrollable ...

[image]

... consider that image ... the scrollbar should be part of the grid itself not below the grid.
When the grid shrinks the pager should shrink and remain visible (both sides of it), and a scrollbar be applied to the data to allow the contents of the grid to be scrolled without losing sight of any of the grid footer.

Comment: This sample is about column resizing, which is different from grid resizing: it's only when you drag the line that separates two columns.

Comment: How about adding css `min-width` on that div element, eg. 300px * number of columns: `<div id="grid" style="min-width: 900px"></div>`, with this when window resizes columns will not shrink insted horizontal scroll will apear.

Comment: because that puts a scrollbar on the grid container not the grid itself.

Comment: ok, that's css problem....set table element min-width: https://dojo.telerik.com/OdiNOzoL

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that :)